# Deployment on Test Server

Tags: visual-studio, deployment

I want to deploy ASP.NET Core Web API project on testing server with database. I have gone through heroku but it doesn't support Dot Net applications. Here are the configurations of my application:

- ASP.NET Core 5 Web API
- SQL Server 2019

Note: I need backend on server so I could test frontend application where ever I am.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following they each have positives and negatives. The first works the best for me.

1. winhost.com has cheap SQL + .NET Core hosting. No affiliation with them other than a happy customer for 10 years or so.
2. Azure, and other cloud hosting also works and is more performant for more money.
3. You could also setup your own server on an old PC (cheapest option)

Comment: your point 3. Is it possible if I setup server on my local pc and access APIs from different pc on a same network?

Comment: Yes that is definitely possible.  If you want to keep it separate from your main PC you could run it inside a virtual machine or a docker container then it's nice and cleanly separated on it's own and you can shut it down when not in use.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with Asphostportal, shared hosting option, they do support both Asp.net core and SQL server. They are pretty cheap, it is around $8/month.